# Derivative of $H$ with respect to $W$ when performing generalized linear squares

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

I am trying to solve a generalized linear squares model with the following form:

$\hat{Y}= X(X'\Omega^{-1}WX)^{-1}X'\Omega^{-1}WY $

$ H= X(X'\Omega^{-1}WX)^{-1}X'\Omega^{-1}W $

$ \Omega$ is the co-variance matrix.

$ W$ is a diagonal matrix that weights a given observation $w_i$ and is normally $I$.

Occasionally a single or multiple diagonal entries in $W$ are updated.

How should a change in $W$ update $H$ without having to recompute $H$ entirely?

This question is related to the following:

[Derivative of a linear model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6580/derivative-of-a-linear-model#_=_).

Comment: This is a good question, but does seem like it may be a better fit on the [math SE site](http://math.stackexchange.com/), are you only interested in the mathematical aspects of this, or are you also wondering about the substantive statistical meaning of changing $W$ (eg)?

Comment: Given the question already regarding derivative of linear model on Cross Validated and that this question falls broadly under regression diagnostics, a discussion here would be appreciated.